# How to retrieve data from data table from Sports Reference using JSoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm attempting to use JSoup to retrieve the amount of wins for a team from a Sports Reference table.

[Specifically, I am trying to receive the following data point highlighted below, with the html code provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyKv7.png)

Below is what I have tried already, but I get a null pointer exception when trying to access the text of this element, telling me that my code is likely not parsing the HTML code correctly.

`Element wins = document.selectFirst("td[data-stat=\"wins\"]");`

What I want is for the text of this element to be 34 (or some number depending on the number of wins for the team).

Answer (score 1):

[Check what your Document was able to read from page and print it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34920028/8370915). If it contains HTML content which can be dynamically added by JavaScript by browser, you need to use as tool Selenium not Jsoup.

[For reading HTML source](https://aboullaite.me/jsoup-html-parser-tutorial-examples/), you can write similar to:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class JSoupHTMLSourceEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String webPage = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/CHI/2020.html#all_team_misc";
        String html = Jsoup.connect(webPage).get().html();
        System.out.println(html);
    }
}
```

Since Jsoup supports [cssSelector](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax), you can try to get an element like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String webPage = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/CHI/2020.html#all_team_misc";
        String html = Jsoup.connect(webPage).get().html();

Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements tds = document.select("#team_misc > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)");
        for (Element e : tds) {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }
}
```

---

But better solution is to use [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)) -  a portable framework for testing web applications ([more details about Selenium tool](https://www.guru99.com/selenium-webtable.html)):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String baseUrl = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/CHI/2020.html#all_team_misc";
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get(baseUrl);
    String innerText = driver.findElement(
        By.xpath("//*[@id="team_misc"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")).getText();  
        System.out.println(innerText); 
    driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Also you can try instead of:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="team_misc"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")).getText();
```

[in this form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41712997/8370915):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id="team_misc"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

---

P.S. In the future it would be useful to add source links from where you want to get information or at least snippet of the DOM structure instead of image.

Comment: Selenium is not necessarily a better solution -- it simply solves a different problem. Jsoup is for parsing the raw DOM as returned from the server (without invoking JS). Selenium is for parsing DOM _after_ invoking JS.